# Add extra column to entity model which is not present in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have following Entity

```
[Table("classes")]
public class Class
{

    public int classID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> grade { get; set; }
    public string classname { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Inactive { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> total { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public Class()
    {}


}
```

This Entity is used at times by a stored procedure and at other times by entityframework (database first approach). Recently i added a field '**total**' that is used by stored procedure. Now the entity framework gives error

> 'unknown column total in field list'

which is as expected.

My question is that is there a way i can set a default value in the onModelCreated function for **total** column so that it ignores the model change exception?

I am using EF6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can apply the `[NotMapped]` attribute to total to tell EF that it's not in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for the Property by setting `DefaultValue` Attribute.

```
[DefaultValue(0)]
public Nullable<int> total { get; set; }
```